# Saving and comparing SQLCe .sdf files in C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, mvvm, architecture

I have a desktop WPF/MVVM application that will need to save/persist scientific data to a SQLCe database using Entity Framework.

The requirements are that the user should be able to save/export/open files as if they were simple word/excel/txt files meaning that just because the system saves to a database, this should be hidden from the user. The user needs to be able to share these "save files (really just a .sdf) with others so that they can import someone elses "save file" into their desktop client instance and compare his results to someone elses results.

I am trying to find out how I can abstract away the fact that there is a database being used for storage while at the same time allowing the freedom of using a open file dialog (for example) to enable the user to export his data file so others can import it into another instance of the desktop application.

There is also the need to compare two or more sets of data against each other. This could manifest as one user comparing his data in the .sdf db against another set of data in a .sdf file from another user.

Any ideas on how to approach this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Entity Framework allows you to work with databases including SQL CE files (currently using it for SQL CE files myself):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx

The connection string contains the file path, so when you use the Open Dialog, you'll retrieve the path and pass it to your context which opens the database connection.

I use Code First which allows you to write C# configuration files that define the database structure (see the link above)

There are some complications with using SQLCE, such as multi-threading (the EF is not inherently thread-safe), and detaching / re-attaching entities.

For comparison between files, I would imagine that you can just create two contexts and write methods to loop through and compare entities across the two.  The slightly tricky parts will be what constitutes a match (is it the ID, matching properties or also child entities) and what to do for new entities.  Not terribly difficult but may require some thought.

I also use the Repository Pattern, which abstracts away operations such as CRUD operations.  This allows you to use multiple file formats or switch formats later on down the road.  For instance, I may switch to XML in the future.